# Can one use parametric regression tests (e.g., Pearson's R2) on summary statistics (that are normal) derived from non-normal data?

Tags: mean, nonparametric, chemometrics

Can one use parametric linear regression tests (e.g., Pearson's R2) on summary statistics (e.g., mean and median) that are normal but derived from non-normal data?

I am specifically dealing with mean and median values of hundreds of metal concentrations in water measurements taken over many months. The water lead and water copper measurements are non-normal (Shapiro-Wilk, p<0.05), but when I calculate monthly averages, the resulting dataset is sometimes normal. Can I use a Pearson's linear regression (a parametric test) between lead and copper average values?

Thanks!

Comment: "Data" are not parametric--only statistical models are.  And even in a nonparametric model, statistics may have distributions that are either completely known or finitely parameterized.  It sounds like you might have a concept of "parametric" that isn't widely shared by statisticians, so could you explain more precisely what it might be?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_statistics vs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_statistics -- your question is unclear. Please edit